# Trigger a Double Click On Page load

Tags: jquery, html

I want to trigger a doubleclick on table's first Row(on Page Load) using Jquery.In My Program I'm using Following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {

    $("table tr td:first").trigger('dbclick');

    },10);

 });..
```

But it is Not Working...How can I do to?? please Give some Idea..

Answer (score 3):

There is an typing error in your code

```
$("table tr td:first").trigger('dbclick');
```

its `dblclick` not `dbclick`. Replace your code as below.

```
$("table tr td:first").trigger('dblclick');
```

Comment: can you pls share your html and `dblclick` function for more clarification?